# How to calculate mean of a list without apply

Tags: r

I have a list like this:

```
test54 <- list(score1=c(3,6,5,7), score2=c(2,3,2,2), score3=c(2,3,4,5), 
               score4=c(1,2,4,5),  score5=c(1,2,1,1))
```

And I would like to calculate the mean without using `apply`, but only with `for` loop and `while` loop.

Can someone show me how?

This is just an exercise. R is my first programming language that I am learning now.

Comment: `for(i in seq_len(length(test54))) print(mean(test54[[i]]))` ? Although the best solution (IMO) would be something like `colMeans(data.frame(test54))`

Comment: Or `lapply(test54, mean)` Or if you really board (like you seem to - no offence), `rowMeans(do.call(rbind, test54))`. You can also use `cat` within a `for` loop, somehting like `for(i in seq_len(length(test54))) cat(mean(test54[[i]]), "\n")`

Comment: Oh, and you asked for a `while` solution too (must... resist...) `i <- 1 ; while(i <= length(test54)) {cat(mean(test54[[i]]), "\n") ; i <- i + 1 }`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks! I was just working on that and I had stuck on 
the second line with `while(i <= length(test54)`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are restricted from using any of apply family function, below could be an approach that may show what is happening inside a for loop and list. Or you could use the approaches (bit more advanced) suggested by David in the comments. But I think a basic understanding on the basics will help.

```
mean_list <- list()
for (i in seq_along(test54)) {
  mean_list[i][[1]] <- mean(test54[i][[1]])
}
mean_list
[[1]]
[1] 5.25

[[2]]
[1] 2.25

[[3]]
[1] 3.5

[[4]]
[1] 3

[[5]]
[1] 1.25


unlist(mean_list)
[1] 5.25 2.25 3.50 3.00 1.25
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And thanks a lot for the unlist function! Did not know about that!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as I see we are in a learning curve here let's illustrate all the weird/unnecessary/correct ways of doing this (that I could think of)

Data

```
test54 <- list(score1=c(3,6,5,7), score2=c(2,3,2,2), score3=c(2,3,4,5), 
               score4=c(1,2,4,5),  score5=c(1,2,1,1))
```

For loops (Not the correct way)

```
for(i in seq_len(length(test54))) print(mean(test54[[i]]))
for(i in seq_len(length(test54))) cat(mean(test54[[i]]), "\n")
i <- 1 ; while(i <= length(test54)) {cat(mean(test54[[i]]), "\n") ; i <- i + 1 } # I can't think of a single reason of using `while`. Ever. Unless you are looking for ways to crash R
```

Hidden for loops (the common way to deal with lists, but still not the correct way in this specific case)

```
lapply(test54, mean)
sapply(test54, mean)
vapply(test54, mean, double(1))
by(stack(test54), stack(test54)$ind, FUN = function(x) mean(x[['values']])) # Very weird and inefficient - don't do this. Ever. (see great alternatives for `by` at the end)
```

Some more inefficient ways to do it (but still better than `for` loops)

```
rowMeans(do.call(rbind, test54))
colMeans(do.call(cbind, test54))
```

The correct way of doing it (but only because we have `colMeans`, not always we have such functions available)

```
colMeans(data.frame(test54))
colMeans(as.data.frame(test54)) # Probably a bit faster
```

Some efficient external packages that can also do it (again, if we wouldn't had the super efficient `colMeans` function)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test54)[, lapply(.SD, mean)]

library(dplyr)
test54 %>%
  data.frame %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
```